# Django - Insert data from uploaded excel file in the database model

Tags: django, excel, database, file-upload, populate

I am trying to populate the database with data from uploaded xlsx file.

I have followed the steps from this tutorial: https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/django-excel/latest/django-excel.pdf

In my case after upload the 404 error page occurs while the web server error log file only shows:

`[Sun Mar 15 20:31:11.075408 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6756] [remote 192.168.1.7:53883] Bad Request: /Project/store/`

I am somehow stuck at this point ... I u/stand that thew form is not valid, but why?

extract from models.py

```
class Store(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    name = models.TextField()
    address = models.TextField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.cod+" "+self.nume
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["cod"]
        verbose_name_plural = "Stores"
```

extract from view.py

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()

def store(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.FILES['file'].save_to_database(
                model=Store,
                mapdict=['code', 'name', 'address', 'city', 'zip'])
            return HttpResponse("OK")
        else:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest()
    else:
        return render(request, 'store.html', {})
```

extract from template - store.html

```
<form action="{% url "store" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group mb-4 mt-3">
        <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Excel file ONLY !</label>
        <input type="file" title="Upload excel file" name="excel_file"
 class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" required="required">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="time" class="mt-4 mb-4 btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

xlsx file data

```
code    | name      | address           | city      | zip
    1   | Store01   | 191-st, Main street       | Calhounn  | 7000
    2   | Store02   | 277-th, River streetGaleria   | Verdounne | 9000
```

Comment: Are you using accessing it locally or from another device using the IP address `192.168.1.7:53883`?\

Comment: I am using a Bitnami VM (192.168.1.3 )hosted on the same machine (192.168.1.7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use "file" as the name of the input element in html.